# Rawurlencode and decode quirk?

Tags: php, html

I have a URL that I'm passing through a jQuery ajax call (using encodeURIComponent) and decoding in PHP at the other end. I found what I thought to be a problem between rawurldecode() at the PHP end, but when using JUST PHP to rawurlencode() and rawurldecode() a test URL, I managed to get the same problem - can someone point out to me what I need to do here?

To reproduce:

```
$thing = rawurlencode("www.nzballet.org.nz?pa=thisthing&parmater1=23a&paramter2=another");
echo $thing;
```

This will produce:

www.nzballet.org.nz%3Fpa%3Dthisthing%26parmater1%3D23a%26paramter2%3Danother

If I then:

```
$rawurl = "www.nzballet.org.nz%3Fpa%3Dthisthing%26parmater1%3D23a%26paramter2%3Danother";
$decoded = rawurldecode($rawurl);
echo $decoded;
```

I get:

www.nzballet.org.nz?pa=thisthing&parmater1=23a¶mter2=another

This is the same output I got when passing between jQuery (ajax) and PHP, so it's got nothing to do with that part of it. I have charset=UTF-8 specified in the HTML header - can someone enlightne me as to why I'm getting that weird character there?

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me:  http://codepad.org/LCjJ6dlO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your web browser is seeing `&para` and assuming you meant `&para;`, which is the entity for a paragraph symbol (¶). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100905/para-turns-into-within-pre for some more discussion on that issue.

To get around it, encode your entities with [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before displaying them:

```
$rawurl = "www.nzballet.org.nz%3Fpa%3Dthisthing%26parmater1%3D23a%26paramter2%3Danother";
$decoded = rawurldecode($rawurl);
echo htmlspecialchars($decoded);
```

From the manual:

> Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be
>   represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings.
>
> ...
>
> '&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'